# How can I remove string after "#"?

Tags: iphone, string, nsstring

There is a string,

> NSString *abcd = @"1992#ABCDTEST"

And I want to remove

> "#ABCDTEST".

And NSString *abcd 
changes to @"1992"

Who can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
NSRange r = [abcd rangeOfString:@"#"];
if (r.location!=NSNotFound)
    abcd=[abcd substringToIndex:r.location-1];
```

Comment: I tried on NSArray... Like this : NSArray *nameSection = [names objectForKey:key];
 
 NSRange r = [nameSection rangeOfString:@"#"];
 if (r.location!=NSNotFound)
  nameSection=[nameSection substringToIndex:r.location-1];

Comment: NSArray isn't a string. I don't know what you are trying to do... What does your NSArray contain? Post relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *chunks = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @"#"];

if ([chunks count] > 0)
{

     NSLog(chunks[0]);
}
```